# Why can't I add data to models in Django database?

Tags: django, python-3.x, database

I can't data to any of the schemas on my database. It gives error HTTP 400 when I click on save. Applicable to all schemas and models.
Images attached.

I expect it to add the data to the model but it says that the page isn't working and returns error 400.

And also, I created another Django project and I was able to add users there. I matched the settings.py file for both the projects and I couldn't spot any difference. Is there some place else I should be looking?

urls.py ->

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chat/', include('chat.urls', namespace='chat')),
    ]
```

No error in the console log

```
[2019/05/27 08:33:58] HTTP GET /admin/login/ 302 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:39500]
[2019/05/27 08:33:58] HTTP GET /admin/ 200 [0.05, 127.0.0.1:39500]
[2019/05/27 08:34:00] HTTP GET /admin/login/rooms/add/ 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:39500]
[2019/05/27 08:34:00] HTTP GET /admin/jsi18n/ 200 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:39500]
```

Repository link-
https://github.com/AdityaAjay/Collabgator

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]

Comment: this screenshots are not enough to determine what is the problem with your code. Please provide codes from your implementation. Also you might want to check your server log, because there it might contain why the error is happening.

Comment: Can you show us your urls.py settings?

Comment: I've added the code from urls.py in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: You need to set debug to True in your settings.py to see the underlying errors. Most probably your database connection settings are not correct or the initial migration has not been done.

Comment: Debug is set to True. How do I check my database connection settings?

Comment: And also, I created another Django project and I was able to add users there. I matched the settings.py file for both the projects and I couldn't spot any difference. Is there some place else I should be looking?

Comment: @AdityaAjay I think you already run migration. Right?

Comment: if you get an error 400, your django console should show you an error. please share the full trace of the error.

Comment: There's no error in the console log. I've updated the question's description to show the console's output.